# Using a print function in parent class, about definition of 'inherited' variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Let's suppose I have a parent class called *figure*:

```
class Figure:
    def __init__(self):        
        self.name = " "
        self.description = " "
        self.data = []

        
    def myprint(self):
        # Print all variables in a special way
```

I want to create several childs of this class (Circle, rectangle...) and I want to use as much inheritance as possible. That's why I want to create a **myprint** function that outputs all the data which is common to all childs, i.e. this one:

```
        self.name = " "
        self.description = " "
        self.data = []
```

What is the correct way to do it?

1. Should I include those lines in class *Figure* and then modify them in every child using

   ```
   Figure.name = 'Circle'
   ```
2. ... Or should I create them in every child? How would I use a common **myprint** function then? This way:

> ```
> class Figure:
>         def __init__(self):        
>                           
>         def myprint(self):
>             # Print all variables in a special way
>
> class Cricle(Figure):
>         def __init__(self, radius):        
>             name='Circle'
>             pass
> ```

Comment: `name = Figure.name = 'Circle'` is pretty nonsensical… – In `myprint` you simply `print(self.name)`, within each child's constructor (or class definition) you set a different value for `self.name`, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Figure:
    name = 'Figure'
    description = "I'm a figure"

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []

    def myprint(self):
        print(self.name, self.description, self.data)


class Circle(Figure):
    name = 'Circle'
    description = "I'm a circle"
```

This is all you need. If the properties aren't specific *to an instance*, but are the same for all class instances, just define them on the class (here `name` and `description`). Only `data` is defined within the constructor because `[]` is mutable and you probably want that to be unique for each instance.

The child class then redefines `name` and `description` with different values. `myprint` of `Figure` instances will print `"Figure"`, while `myprint` of `Circle` instances will print `"Circle"`. That's because `self.name` refers to the `name` attribute of the current object, and that value will differ based on whether it's a `Figure` or `Circle`.

Comment: I have a few questions: 1) What happens when I have variables *specific to an instance*? I mean things like *radius* which will be instance dependant for class **Circle**. 2) What happens if I never assign *name* in **Circle** and use *myprint*, Will it print 'I am a figure'? 3) Could you explain me a bit more what you mean with "Only data is defined within the constructor because `[]` is mutable and you probably want that to be unique for each instance"?

Comment: 1) You pass it to `__init__` and store it on `self`: `def __init__(self, radius): self.radius = radius`. 2) Yes.

Comment: @D1X If you defined `data` the same way as `name`, every instance of `Figure` would share the same `data` variable. If you add something to the list, every other instance will see the added data as well. Because it's a *class attribute*, not an *instance attribute*. Because you're only creating *one list*, not one for each instance.

Comment: Also, Is it necessary to create the variables at **Figure** and then change them at every child to be able to print them in **Figure**?

Comment: It's not **necessary** to change them in every child; if you don't redefine those attributes in child classes, the parent's class' value will be used instead. That's *inheritance*.

Comment: Forget my other question. I know parent class' value will be used, I am asking if I will be able to use in the parent class a variable which is initialized in a child (That's what I do in *myprint*).

Comment: You inherit the method `myprint` too. That method uses the `self` variable. The attributes of that variable will vary depending on which instance you call the method on. The code of `myprint` is the same, the contents of `self` are different. That's a key concept of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you define in `__init__` are instance variables.
I suppose you are looking for class variables, or rather constants which are exactly the same, but written with all capitals by convention.
Also, take a look on the `__str__` method [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).
The correct way therefore would be:

```
class Figure:
    NAME = "Figure"

    def __str__(self):
        """ override me """
        return "I am a {name} and have the default __str__".format(name=self.NAME)

class Circle(Figure):
    NAME = "Circle"

    def __init__(self, x, y, r):
        self.x, self.y, self.r = x, y, r

    def __str__(self):
        return "I am a {name} at ({x}, {y}) with radius {r}".format(
            name=NAME, x=self.x, y=self.y, r=self.r)
```

Now all you need to do to get a correct output is to run

```
f = Figure()
c = Circle(1, 2, 3)
print(f)
print(c)
```

Which will output

```
I am a Figure and have my __str__ not overwritten
I am a Circle at (1, 2) with radius 3
```